# A Ruby implementation of derangement (secret santa) algorithm

Tags: algorithm, ruby

A [secret santa gift exchange](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_elephant_gift_exchange) is a game where each player is randomly assigned a person to whom they anonymously give a gift. The algorithm is referred to as [Derangement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement).

For example, given the following players:

> Mohamad, Carolina, Sami, Tania, Ikram, José

A game may be:

> Mohamad gets Sami
>   Carolina gets José
>   Sami gets Tania
>   Tania gets Mohamad
>   Ikram gets Carolina
>   José gets Ikram

The important rules are:

1. A person can not be assigned to themselves.
2. A person can only be assigned to another person once.
3. Assignment must be random.

### Implementation

This is my object oriented implementation. I do not like my `random_player_for` implementation. It seems procedural and the use of temporary flags seems like a code smell.

How would you improve this implementation?

```
class Derangement
  attr_reader :game

  # for convenience
  # PLAYERS = %w[Mohamad Carolina Sami Tania Jose Ikram Rabii Ahmad Kazem]

  def initialize(players)
    @players = players
    @santas = players.dup
    @game = {}
  end

  def solve
    @santas.each do |santa|
      @game[santa] = random_player_for(santa)
    end
  end

private

  def random_player_for(santa)
    found = false
    until found do
      player = @players.sample
      unless player == santa
        found = true
        @players.delete(player)
      end
    end
    player
  end
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm a bit unsure about whether the question is about a game of Secret Santa or if it's actually about derangement, specifically. Derangement requires that no element can appear *in its original position*. <strike>But that's irrelevant for a game of Secret Santa, since there's no ordering to speak of.</strike>

*Edit:* As tokland rightly points out in the comments derangement *is* of course related to the game. I wasn't thinking it through.

For derangement, [Rosetta Code has a Ruby implementation](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Permutations/Derangements#Ruby) you might be able to use or learn from.

For a game of Secret Santa, though, the specs are pretty much as you summed up in your 3 rules (although #3 "Assignment must be random" is a bit difficult to define/verify.) So here, things can be simplified; you need not worry about derangement "by itself" as long as the rules are obeyed. For instance, you might simply do:

```
players = %w[Mohamad Carolina Sami Tania Ikram Jose].shuffle
players << players.first # repeat the first player

assignments = players.each_cons(2).to_a
```

which will give you an array of santa/gift-receiver pairs such as:

```
[["Carolina", "Ikram"],
 ["Ikram", "Mohamad"],
 ["Mohamad", "Jose"],
 ["Jose", "Tania"],
 ["Tania", "Sami"],
 ["Sami", "Carolina"]]
```

Alternatively, you can get the "Santa targets" for several rounds by doing something like

```
players = %w[Mohamad Carolina Sami Tania Ikram Jose].shuffle
assignments = players.each_with_index.map do |santa, index|
  others = players.rotate(index+1)[0...-1]
  [santa, others]
end
```

Which will give you something like

```
[["Tania", ["Mohamad", "Sami", "Ikram", "Carolina", "Jose"]],
 ["Mohamad", ["Sami", "Ikram", "Carolina", "Jose", "Tania"]],
 ["Sami", ["Ikram", "Carolina", "Jose", "Tania", "Mohamad"]],
 ["Ikram", ["Carolina", "Jose", "Tania", "Mohamad", "Sami"]],
 ["Carolina", ["Jose", "Tania", "Mohamad", "Sami", "Ikram"]],
 ["Jose", ["Tania", "Mohamad", "Sami", "Ikram", "Carolina"]]]
```

There's a pattern of course (if you've given Ikram a gift, next you'll be giving Carolina a gift, then José, etc.). But if it's Secret Santa, the players shouldn't be able to figure that out anyway unless they cheat (and if they do, well, all bets are off).

You could of course use [`Array#combination`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-combination) or [`Array#permutation`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-permutation) to achieve similar results. I highly encourage you to check out all of the built-in array methods, and those included from [the `Enumerable` module](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html). There's a lot of good stuff there.

As for a more OOP approach, I wouldn't make a class called "Derangement". Derangement is a *method*. It's an action, an operation, a means of achieving a certain result or state - not something that is itself stateful.
The simple solution, given your code, is to rename you class to "Game" or something along those lines.

Comment: @Flambino: AFAICS the Secret Santa game is 100% related to derangement, since `persons.zip(persons.shuffle_with_derangement)` is the solution to the problem.

Comment: @tokland Ah, you're right, of course. I'll update my answer - thanks!

Comment: @tokland I don't understand something. Is `shuffle_with_derangement` a ruby method? I can't find it in the docs.

Comment: @Mohamad No, you must write `Array#shuffle_with_derangement` yourself :) It was just an example to show the relation (but you can actually implement it this way).

Comment: @tokland Ha! Of course, that would be too easy! I'm not at a level yet to understand your example, so I assumed the method existed.

Comment: @Mohamad: Ruby has a Array#shuffle method, but of course it does not enforce that all elements end up in different positions as you need. But I think this is correct path for the abstraction (adding a generic abstraction to Array) instead of creating a custom object.

Answer (score 2):

Your `random_player_for()` method can be better expressed as:

```
  def random_player_for(santa)
    loop do
      player = @players.sample
      if player != santa
        @players.delete(player)
        return player
      end
    end
  end
```

However, you should recognize that there is a **possibility for an infinite loop,** if all other players have already been assigned to each other and there is only one loner left.

The following method would be an improvement in two ways:

- Predictable running time
- Detection of a loner

```
  def random_player_for(players, santa)
    others = players.reject { |player| player == santa }
    if others.empty?
      throw LonerException.new(santa)
    else
      return players.delete(others.sample)
    end
  end
```

Then, if `solve()` catches the `LonerException`, it could `retry` all the assignments from scratch.

```
  def solve
    begin
      @game = {}
      players = @players.dup
      @santas.each { |santa| @game[santa] = random_player_for(players, santa) }
    rescue LonerException
      retry
    end
  end
```

Better yet, modify `random_player_for()` such that when there are only two players left, and at least one of them has not yet been given an assignment as a Santa, take care to assign them in such a way that there is no loner.

Comment: Thank you. I maybe wrong, but I can not see a scenario where a loner is left. The number of santas should always be equal to the number of players. So every santa will be matched with player other than himself. How can a loner be left over?

Comment: Take your example: { Mohamad, Carolina, Sami, Tania, Ikram, José }. Let's say the first five form a cycle: Mohamad → Carolina, Carolina → Sami, Sami → Tania, Tania  → Ikram, Ikram → Mohamad. Poor José is a loner and would have to be assigned to himself.

Comment: I see. But doesn't your implementation of the `random_player_for` leave the chance of duplicate assignments? No where I see we are modifying the `player` array. So what's to stop the same player being picked on another iteration? Perhaps we should change `return others.sample` to `players.delete(others.sample)`?